# SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('EASTERN','(EAST)([^ERN])','\1 ') FROM dualRegexp_Replace only portion of word in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying but i'm failing to achieve my result.It looks simple ,don't know where I am missing.I need to separate word

```
EASTHEMISPHERE ==> EAST HEMISPHERE
WESTHALF ==> WEST HALF
EASTERN ==> EASTERN
WESTERN ==> WESTERN

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('EASTERN','(EAST)[(^ERN)]','\1 ') FROM dual
==> EAST RN   ..this is wrong.I am missing something
BUT
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('EASTSIDE','(EAST)[(^ERN)]','\1 ') FROM dual
==> EAST IDE  Why is the S  missing
```

Or is there a better way to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[(^ERN)]
```

Doesn't do what you intend for it to ([see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).  To preclude matching a sequence of characters like this, you would need a lookahead, like `(?!ERN)`, which are not supported by the `POSIX ERE` flavor of regular expression used by Oracle.

However, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('EASTERN','(EAST(ERN)?)(.*)','\1 \3') FROM dual
```

Comment: The Second sql worked perfect..1st one didn't work.Thanks a lot for the quick turnaround.Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thought I had seen that lookaround assertions were added to regexp functions in 10g, but doing a bit of poking around, it definitely appears I was mistaken.